# Should minimalistic tags and synonyms be used for anime with different series?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, lumping-and-splitting

For example fullmetal alchemist, code geass and numerous other animes have different series, should we minimize the tags and just use the standard one and use synonyms or should tags exist for each of the series?

Personally I think the standard tag with synonyms will work the best, thoughts?

Comment: i.e http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/116/was-lelouch-the-person-driving-the-cart-in-the-last-scene-of-the-last-episode-of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be as straightforward as it looks.

In one way, just making synonyms is ok. This, as you mentioned, will help to group up questions instead of splitting them to 100 different tags. For example, *Code Geass R2* can effectively be a synonym of *Code Geass* (I see no problems with this; if anyone does, please tell me).

On the other hand, this definitely can not be used blindly for each and every series. 
For example, we have *FMA* and *FMA:Brotherhood*. Making them synonyms would be (in my opinion) a huge mistake, since the series' stories are just different, and it's even possible that the same question can be answered differently depending on whether it is related to *FMA* or *FMA:Brotherhood*.

So I would say that *if* the suggested synonym can not possible confuse the question-posters and the answerers, it's acceptable. But should rather be handled manually for each specific tag, because there's really no rule of thumb here.

Comment: Index and Railgun is another good example of, "extremely related, but not the same".