# Should multiple continuities have individual tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, lumping-and-splitting

Some anime and manga series have multiple continuities, such as *Fullmetal Alchemist* (the manga and *Brotherhood* follow the same story while the original was only partly based on the manga) and *Evangelion* (the *Rebuild* continuity has strayed completely from the original anime, and the manga is completely different also).

I read through [this question](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212/should-we-have-separate-tags-for-the-dragon-ball-series), but it mostly covers multiple tags for different parts of the same continuity.

So, what I wonder is: Should we have tags for each separate continuity? Such as [fullmetal-alchemist](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fullmetal-alchemist) and [fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood); [neon-genesis-evangelion](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neon-genesis-evangelion) and [rebuild-of-evangelion](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebuild-of-evangelion); and so on? [This answer](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/88/274) seemed to suggest we should, but no changes have been made to questions pertaining to *FMA: Brotherhood*; should they be?

Comment: related: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/84/should-minimalistic-tags-and-synomoms-be-used-for-anime-with-different-series/88#88

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Yup, I already linked that in my post, but thanks! :)

Answer (score 7):

For Fullmetal Alchemist, having separate tags for `fullmetal-alchemist` and `fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood` would get really confusing. Fullmetal Alchemist (the 2005 anime) is different from Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood, but Fullmetal Alchemist (the manga) is essentially the same as Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood, so that will lead to a lot of problems. As said in [Regarding tag sprawl](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222/regarding-tag-sprawl?lq=1), it can just be clarified in the question which one is being asked about.

For Neon Genesis Evangelion, and in general, I think having a policy of fewer-is-better should be used when regarding tags. It can be clarified in a question what is being asked about, just as it can be clarified whether a manga or an anime is being asked about.

Comment: I would have no problem having *Brotherhood* and the manga as synonyms, since their differences are minimal. However, it helps people who are looking for specific *Brotherhood* information, as it would in the *Rebuild* canon. I'm personally thinking these should be treated as different stories entirely. Unfortunately, aside from a quick "mention" in that thread you posted, it doesn't seem to be discussed much.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer here is "it depends".

Are the very significant differences between the versions of the series? Plot-wise? Character-wise?

In the case of [fullmetal-alchemist](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fullmetal-alchemist), yes, there are. However, because the *manga* is called **Fullmetal Alchemist**, while the "original" anime is called **Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood**, I'd argue it would make more sense to have a [fullmetal-alchemist](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fullmetal-alchemist) for the manga and brotherhood, and a [fullmetal-alchemist-2003](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fullmetal-alchemist-2003), for the 2003 series.

However, these cases should be handled on a case-to-case basis. If the variations are fundamentally different, yes. There should a different tag for it. Where the most "popular" tag ([fullmetal-alchemist](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fullmetal-alchemist) is considered more popular than [fullmetal-alchemist-2003](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fullmetal-alchemist-2003) in this context) goes to the *canonical, official* series.

Comment: I agree here, though I hadn't even thought of that point about the "official" canon. The problem is in something like *Evangelion* in which multiple continuities are canon and official. We'd need tags like *neon-genesis-evangelion*, *neon-genesis-evangelion-manga*, and *rebuild-of-evangelion*.