# Should Railgun and Index become two separate tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, lumping-and-splitting

Sometimes I get confused about this, should I tag my question with [toaru-majutsu-no-index](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toaru-majutsu-no-index) or [toaru-kagaku-no-railgun](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toaru-kagaku-no-railgun)? And I ended up using both tags for my question.

Based on the question about [How are "A Certain Magical Index" and "A Certain Scientific Railgun" connected?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2675/how-are-a-certain-magical-index-and-a-certain-scientific-railgun-connected), these two anime are the same. Or so I understand the answer, maybe I got it wrong?

And I saw a question about [Should multiple continuities have individual tags?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308/should-multiple-continuities-have-individual-tags) and according to Kuwaly's answer,

> For Neon Genesis Evangelion, and in general, I think having a policy of fewer-is-better should be used when regarding tags

Don't you think the same policy should apply for Railgun and Index? Can't we just make a synonym or something?

Comment: I would be in support of a tag synonym

Comment: i agree with @ToshinouKyouko but how would be called it, toaru?

Comment: @Memor-X Raildex is widely used

Comment: What about sticking with the name of the first series?

Comment: use original LN title? But I don't know what is it..

Comment: @ShinobuOshino The original LN title is "Toaru Majutsu no Index"

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it's a good idea. Index and Railgun are two series that play in the same universe and share some characters, but that's all (only one arc is happens in both animes yet (and doesn't share much, actually), the others are completely independent. I don't know about the Daihasei Festival Arc, but it seems like they are independent, too). One could have seen Railgun without knowing of Index (or the other way round) and can answer the question if it is *really* about Railgun.

Index and Railgun are just too distinct to be handled with one tag, imo.

Comment: FMA 2005 and Brotherhood also really different though... but we only have one tag... I know maybe because the manga but still,, If we going to give this two tag shouldn't FMA also have at least two tag?

Comment: @ShinobuOshino there are two reasons why fma has only one tag: 1.) FMA 2005 is only known as FMA (because that's the name) and FMA BH is known as FMA, too (because it's the story of the manga FMA) Nobody could see which storyline is meant if both tags are usable and "FMA" is chosen 2.) It's just an alternate storyline with the same main-characters and the same beginning. Railgun/Index is different because it only shares the universe.