# Why do FMA and FMA brotherhood not have different tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, lumping-and-splitting

I have started FMA brotherhood recently and I want to follow its question. But then A&M have only one tag for it is [fullmetal-alchemist](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fullmetal-alchemist), covering FMA manga, FMA anime and FMA brotherhood. But as most of us already know FMA anime and FMA brotherhood anime are different shows, so why not use two different tag for them? I even suggest to make three tag: one for manga, two for each anime, as FMA anime is also non canon to FMA manga but FMA brotherhood is.

I know its been discussed in [meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308/should-multiple-continuities-have-individual-tags/309#309), [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7248290#7248290) before but seems like it still hold confusion if one want to follow one anime and not other.

We even have tag for [dragon-ball-gt](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-gt), [dragon-ball-super](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-super) and [akito-the-exiled](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/akito-the-exiled), even when they are canon to main continuity but not for FMA brotherhood which is different show then FMA?

Comment: While I'm not sure having separate tags for this series is the best option, I agree that we should probably be consistent in our tagging approach

Comment: @AyanoSugiura both are different series and non canon to each other, so their should be some differentiation to identify each.

Comment: Tags exist to separate areas of expertise and both series are so similar in content that it was decided that if you know one, you shouldn't have trouble with the other. Or that's what I think happened. You could easily get up to speed by watching the other series if you know one already.

Comment: @HakashinouShinonouko this gives no opportunity to avoid one of them.

Comment: I don't think the intention to *avoid* either was ever in anyone's mind.

Comment: @HakashinouShinonouko There is a TV show Being human made in UK, then its reboot was made in US.  Now both Movies.se and scifi.se had two tags for them, one for each. Both series are similar in first season but changes a lot after it ( same like FMA), now you can't force someone to know being human US show too while answering being human UK. So making one tag is like forcing someone to know both before checking into that tag.

Comment: Someone told me it's because brotherhood anime is based on manga, and the manga is titled fullmetal alchemist, without brotherhood, so to avoid confusion (or to add them) we decide to only make one tag for all series

Comment: maybe we can have [tag:fullmetal-alchemist-2003] and [tag:fullmetal-alchemist]?

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ its already there in question itself, even with related chat discussion

Comment: We're inconsistent on our policy of multiple continuities. If we were to do separate tags, brotherhood runs over the tag limit so we'll need to abbreviate it [tag:fma-brotherhood]. IMO It doesn't make much sense to make a dedicated tag for the manga as there is little to no difference from the anime adaptation. While we don't get many questions for gundam, the series falls under the same umbrella. On a related note, there might be a need for a general series tag for question involving multiple continuities. Instead of naming all the gundam titles, a [tag:gundam-uc] tag might be useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently, we're in the process of spliting different continuities and spin-offs into separate tags discussed in [this meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2700/63), with some compromises.

### Pilot proposal

I would like to use the FMA series as a test pilot for our tag continuity change. If successfully implemented, there will likely be a meta of franchise tags to help users keep track of them.

What I propose is the following:

There will be a general franchise tag [fma-series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fma-series) (the full title is too long, adding series distinctly defines it as a franchise tag, to avoid confusion with the original series in the franchise), a tag for the original 2003 anime (and movie) [fullmetal-alchemist-2003](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fullmetal-alchemist-2003)(needs to be distinguishable from from just "fullmetal-alchemist" because users will tend to only use "fullmetal-alchemist" regardless of whether or not they are talking about brotherhood or the original series), for FMA:Brotherhood [fma-brotherhood](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fma-brotherhood), which will include the manga. Synonyms will be added to better associate the two when querying "fullmetal-a..." (all three tags should appear).

There will be an explanation in the tag wiki of the franchise about what is covered in what tags and how to use them.

All FMA question will include the franchise tag and w/e respective series tag. E.g., [fma-series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fma-series)[fullmetal-alchemist-2003](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fullmetal-alchemist-2003) for questions about the original series, and just [fma-series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fma-series) for franchise specific ones applicable to either the original or Brotherhood.

### For standalone series

For series with no spin-offs and only one continuity, the series tag will function like a franchise tag, until there is a need to distinguish them.