# A certain multivariate experiment: Testing changes to series tags based on story continuity

Tags: discussion, tags, lumping-and-splitting

The meta is written in order to better explain the intent behind the changes to site tags in regards to series continuity as noted in [this meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2673/why-fma-and-fma-brotherhood-didnt-have-different-tag/2714#2714).

This experiment is being done in an attempt to access the viability of such a change on a community-wide basis. If it is deemed that there is little to no improvement in how users interact, understand, and/or use these tags, the described changes will be reverted.

### What series will be affected?

The two series franchise have been chosen for this experiment based on prior feedback:

- [fma-series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fma-series) including [fullmetal-alchemist-2003](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fullmetal-alchemist-2003), and [fma-brotherhood](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fma-brotherhood)
- [dragonball-series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonball-series) including [dragon-ball](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball), [dragon-ball-z](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-z), [dragon-ball-gt](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-gt), [dragon-ball-super](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-super)

Fullmetal Alchemist series questions will require a franchise tag along with a series tag. E.g., [fma-series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fma-series)[fma-brotherhood](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fma-brotherhood) for questions on the Brotherhood anime.

The Dragonball series questions will require only the tag of the series continuity asked.

Because many of our questions have been more related to anime rather than manga, the tags will skew in favor of the anime series naming. That is not to say that questions specifically related to their respective manga will be ignored. Users can still use [dragon-ball-manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-manga) for the Dragonball manga series and [fullmetal-alchemist-manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fullmetal-alchemist-manga) for the Fullmetal Alchemist manga series.

- If you were to ask a question about the difference between the FMA: Brotherhood anime and FMA manga, you would use the following tags: [fma-series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fma-series)[fma-brotherhood](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fma-brotherhood)[fullmetal-alchemist-manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fullmetal-alchemist-manga)
- For question involving the anime series and the respective manga for Dragonball: [dragon-ball-super](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-super)[dragon-ball-manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-manga)
- For general franchise related questions, just the franchise tag is needed for either series.

### What's being tested?

Two variables will be used for testing here:

- Whether requiring a franchise tag in addition to a series tag referring to the continuity is viable or not (for Fullmetal Alchemist)
- Whether just splitting the continuities based on the anime title is enough (For Dragonball)

The control part of the experiment will be all of the current series tags, of which there will *not change in any way*.

This experiment will be last for a **1 to 2 month period**, **starting the Sunday of January 17, 2016**, starting at 0 UTC, during which period the community can provide feedback using this meta. If this tag experiment is deemed unviable by a majority of users, then this experiment will conclude prematurely and all changes reverted to how they were prior. If however, there is data and feedback to show that the tag changes are indeed viable (i.e. improves user experience), a second round of discussion will be made in order to discuss community wide rollout.

To make things easier for users to understand, the respective tag wikis for the abovementioned series will include a more indepth explanation of how to use these tags.

Some points to consider within this experiment are:

- Does the added complexity help understanding the question topic, without the need to explain in the question title or body? I.e., know that I'm talking about a specific continuity without explicitly having to say it
- Will having less generalized series tags help with organization and searchability? Each question has five slots for tags, which will allow us to test if including more tags will have any added benefit or if they will just clutter up the site
- How users react to more drastic changes in tag policy

It's understandable that this experiment seems a bit forced, but in order to give some sort of resolution to the ongoing back and forth discussion on whether or not more specification and less generalization in terms of story continuity is needed, the idea of field testing the change on a limited scale was made.

### Why should you care/participate?

Participation is completely voluntary. Because there has been a lot of back and forth about whether we should do something or how we should act with regards to tagging, I believe that putting these hypotheses to the test and getting actual results might give us a better idea of the direction we should focus on for our site policies. While we can't always see eye to eye on every thing, we should try to give each other a chance to prove themselves to be correct or incorrect through a bit of experimentation.

During this time, all users are encouraged to ask more question relating the the Dragon Ball and Fullmetal Alchemist series.

Any questions, concerns, feedback, or complaints can be addressed in this meta or on our [main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-).

Comment: If fully adopted, wouldn't this (approximately) double both the number of tags on the average question _and_ the number of tags in use? Is that an acceptable outcome? (Would it make moderation considerably more difficult?)

Comment: Yes, but it's been discussed that there is reasonable cause to split series tags based on story continuity. The feasibility of a franchise that is has some mixed opinion. This is a test to see if it's viable for a full-site rollout.

Comment: How should the FMA films be treated? Personally, I'd be comfortable using [tag:fullmetal-alchemist-2003] for the _Conqueror of Shamballa_ film (iirc it falls reasonably into that continuity). However, I'm not sure about _Sacred Star of Milos_. Apparently that's generally not treated as "canon" for the manga / FMA:B, but the story IIRC is based on that continuity. (Currently there are 2-3 questions about the film on the site.)