# Somebody's adding series tags, possibly incorrectly

Tags: discussion, tags

I'd like to draw attention of suggested edit reviewers to a certain user who is currently adding Dragon Ball series tag to a bunch of already DB-tagged questions:

https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/31640

I thought series tags should be used only for questions which directly ask about something that applies to all the works in the series? Or am I wrong and all those edits are correct?

Comment: What did we end up deciding as the outcome of [this meta post](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/a-certain-multivariate-experiment-testing-changes-to-series-tags-based-on-story)? That's what will determine if these tag edits were correct. (I was under the impression they were correct, but I remembered wrong; the older meta never says that, so it's probably something we should decide.)

Comment: well, I'm not sure what happened here so I just brought it up for others to discuss since I'm not very well acquainted with the discussion you linked to and dragon ball series neither.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. That discussion was a long time ago, and I had remembered wrongly how it went—I'd thought we were doing the "series tag + franchise tag" for both Dragon Ball and Full Metal Alchemist, but it turns out we were doing "series tag only" for Dragon Ball. For that reason I approved some of those tag edits, but I started skipping them to let others take a look in case I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A while ago we ran an experiment to see if it would be helpful to adopt a Sci-fi and Fantasy-inspired approach to tagging continuities where every question has a franchise tag and questions that focus mostly on a single series would additionally carry a series tag. That experiment was started in [A certain multivariate experiment: Testing changes to series tags based on story continuity](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/a-certain-multivariate-experiment-testing-changes-to-series-tags-based-on-story).

Under the terms of that experiment, we were going to do SF&F-style tagging for Full Metal Alchemist, where every question has the [fma-series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fma-series) tag and questions focusing on a specific continuity would also carry a tag for that continuity (e.g. [fullmetal-alchemist-2003](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fullmetal-alchemist-2003)). We were going to do single tags for the Dragon Ball series, if a question only concerns DBZ, it has the [dragon-ball-z](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-z) tag, and if it concerns the entire franchise (e.g. something like "Why is Goku's hair so spiky?", since Goku's hair appears in every Dragon Ball series), it would have the [dragon-ball-series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-series) tag only.

It seems like this user was trying to apply the rules we were using for [fma-series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fma-series) to the [dragon-ball-series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-series) tag. I, at least, was also confused about this point and ignorantly approved a few of these edits, but when they kept on coming I started skipping them so that another member of the community could double check. (Plus, bumping a ton of old posts to the front page for a tag edit isn't cool; a few is fine, but more than three or four is a little excessive.)

As far as I can tell, we never did come to a conclusion about which tag scheme we were going to adopt. The way we were tagging Dragon Ball questions was basically the system we already had, so we should probably collect opinions from people who participated in the Full Metal Alchemist tags under this system about whether they think it would be good to adopt it for other series with several different continuities.

(For the record, at the time I supported the scheme we were using for Full Metal Alchemist. I still think it works really well for cases like Sci-fi and Fantasy where you have huge franchises with multiple independent works, but it is pretty high maintenance.)

Answer (score 0):

I've rolled [this one](https://anime.stackexchange.com/revisions/28325/4) and [this one](https://anime.stackexchange.com/revisions/2841/5) back, but [this one](https://anime.stackexchange.com/revisions/3010/3) only serves to annoy me.

Why would I consider rolling these back?  Because adding the whole "series" tag is *not helpful* in my mind.

These questions are about specific Dragon Ball series, and not of the series as a whole, so I see ***no*** value in adding the "whole" series tag.  My gut tells me that a tag for the whole series has dubious value at best anyway, but I'd like to leave that for another discussion on another day.

My opinion on the matter:  keep the overall series tag if it's asking a question about the overall series; otherwise, the more specific series tag is *plenty*.