# Let's take a look back at our site policies (2016 Edition)

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation, policies

[Last year](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2564/lets-take-a-look-back-at-our-site-policies-2015-edition) we asked you what were the pain points of the site for you. Now that a year has passed (almost to the day), We'd like to know what has changed in this list. Are there any new problems? Are old policies out of date? etc.

The intent is to have a concrete list of to-fix items for us as a community to fix. Also it will give [our soon-to-be-elected new moderator](https://anime.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) some grounding on which to start.

Here is the template, unchanged from last year:

> **Policy:** (and what it needs) (e.g., [needs-update](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/needs-update), [deprecated](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deprecated), [needs-review](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/needs-review), [contradictory](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contradictory), [needs-clarification](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/needs-clarification), etc.)
>
> *{{Brief description and link to relevant meta (if applicable). If two or more policies are contradictory to one another, post links to all of them where applicable.}}*
>
> **Reason:**
>
> *{{What needs to be brought to attention}}*
>
> **Remarks:**
>
> *{{Optional, any personal remarks or suggestions on said policy}}*

After a period to collect feedback, we will start to work through these - taking note of which are the most important to the site's users. We will open the floor to each topic and try to find a good solution to them all.

The intent of this meta is to collect problems areas our site, particularly with it's policies, so that we can build proper queuing system to address these problems one by one, instead of dividing our attention across multiple issues. This way, we give the users a transparency and clarify behind the state of policy making for the community.

Answer (score 4):

**Policy**: Tagging multiple continuities in a franchise [needs-clarification](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/needs-clarification)

Back in January, we started an experiment on tagging multiple continuities, as described in [A certain multivariate experiment: Testing changes to series tags based on story continuity](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2719/7579) as a response to the discussion on [Policy Review: Tagging - separate continuities](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2690/7579).

**Reason**:

As far as I could tell, we never finished the experiment or declared a result. This led a confused user to start tagging Dragon Ball questions with the [dragon-ball-series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-series) tag, and at least one confused edit reviewer (me) to approve those edits, as described in [Somebody's adding series tags, possibly incorrectly](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3891/7579).

**Remarks**:

I argued for the more complex tagging policies we tried with Full Metal Alchemist [here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2700/7579), but I think if we do adopt it we should limit it to certain franchises since it is more work to maintain. I have some ideas on how to decide that we can discuss when this policy comes up for review.

Comment: I'm addressing it [here](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3906/policy-suggestion-applying-series-continuity-and-franchise-tags-globally-on-thi).

Answer (score 3):

**Policy**: When is it necessary to use spoiler [needs-clarification](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/needs-clarification)

**Reason**: Consensus on whether to use and how to use spoilers on the site is not well fleshed out and requires a bit of ironing. Many of the other recreational SEs have a clear policy about spoiler. We should at least try to follow suit and make things clearer for users.

**Remarks**: We've been very inconsistent in our spoiler policy on both the site and chat. This has irked many users and discouraged them from participation.

Comment: I made a mistake while preparing that flowchart apparently. Will post a new version later.