# Scope discussion: Splitting anime-style game questions from anime/manga

Tags: discussion, tags, lumping-and-splitting

While we don't get many of them we do have a couple of popular questions and tags where there is a bit of overlap between the game continuity and related anime and manga spin-offs.

One popular and notable one in particular is [pokemon](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon).

While they have commonalities, each series has it's distinct type of distinction, such as it's story and worldbuilding. In my opinion, these the game continuity should be seperate from the anime and manga continuities. This can alleviate some of the ambiguity on questions that ask about the worlds specific questions.

In that regard, I would like to propose changing the current [pokemon](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon) tag into a [pokemon-series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-series) franchise tag, have the game related questions tagged as [pokemon-game](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-game), the anime with as their respective series name: [pokemon-anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-anime), [pokemon-generations](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-generations), [pokemon-origins](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-origins), etc. The same with the manga: [pokemon-adventures](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-adventures), [pokemon-electric-boogaloo](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-electric-boogaloo), [pokemon-reburst](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-reburst), etc.

Series like the Tales series could have similar treatment, such as a general franchise tag for [tales-series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tales-series), [tales-zestiria-game](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tales-zestiria-game), [tales-zestiria-x](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tales-zestiria-x), etc.

These tags will be added on an as needed basis. While it does cause a bit of fragmentation, bu we can start applying the [prefix schema](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3907/63) idea suggested by senshin to keeping things consistent, while maintaining distiction between anime/manga and games.

For popular franchises, we should look at updating and maintaining the franchise tag's tag wikis to include the all the currently series tags within the franchise for better recordkeeping.

What does the community think about such a change?

Comment: I think the major problem with this is that the most frequently used tags show up highest when question askers search for the tag and as a result mistagging may happen.

Comment: Will this open for other media types like pokemon-manga and pokemon-anime pokemon-go etc?

Comment: Pokemon Go should be off-topic. There are multiple pokemon manga, while only one Pokemon anime. All other anime are short ovas, specials of said anime,  or seoerate shorts. The manga has at least 4 seperate and distinct spin-offs. Anything that fits under a [tag:pokemon-manga] general tag should also fit under a tag:pokemon-series] tag. So a general tag for pikemon manga seems unfeasible to me.

Comment: Pokemon go does not have a history. We only address questions about history, plot and the underlying fictional universe therein. so GO is offtopic. @ToshinouKyouko

Answer (score 5):

Standing at 108 questions, pokemon is the seventh biggest franchise tag right now.

In my view, splitting tags are useful when one of the following conditions apply:

- It helps distinguish what version or field under a specific subject is addressed. For example in SO a [java-4](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java-4) or [java-8](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java-8) are almost incompatible from one another, because the API are radically different. Two questions about exactly the same problem wouild be able to exist side-by-side because the answers to one version would not apply to the other one. Both might be tagged [java](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java) but the split in sub-tags is justified.
- It helps clarify what the OP is asking about, when from the text of the question it could be ambiguous. In RPG there are [rules-as-written](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) and [rules-as-intended](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-intended). Both are questions for rules interpretations, but the answers may even contradict each other.

I think there are differences in the pokemon games and pokemon anime that afford separate tags. But I'd stop there. Remember we only address the story/plot side of the games.